# Android recycler view inside on scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

i have

MAIN VIEW

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_products"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    />
</ScrollView>
```

On my template adapter, i have a another recycler adapter for child views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:background="@color/GRAY"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_for_specification_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**The code work, but when user scroll on android device, the parent scrollView does not allow me to scroll over the recycler view (1)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code you have recylerview inside scroll view, this is wrong.

**Option 1:** If scroll view has not any other child view than remove it and just use recyclerview and also remove `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false`

And your Main View code looks like this;

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_products"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
```

**Option 2:** If scroll view has also other child including recyclerview than you should use nestedscrollview like below code:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbars="none">
      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/sellerProduct"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:src="@drawable/iphone"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false
         android:id="@+id/productList"/>
      </LinearLayout>
   </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use NestedScrollview instead of scrollview and use `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` for recycler_products recyclerview not in both

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_products"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    />
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to scroll it is because of this line

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`.

Change it to True, so you can enable the scrolling:

`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`.